# NPM integration doesn't seem to work in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, npm, playframework-2.0, sbt, playframework-2.5

There is a paragraph in the documentation that says :

> npm can be used as well as WebJars by declaring a package.json file in
>   the root of your project. Assets from npm packages are extracted into
>   the same lib folder as WebJars so that, from a code perspective, there
>   is no concern whether the asset is sourced from a WebJar or from an
>   npm package.

Unfortunatly, this is the only mention of NPM in the whole documentation, and when I run my application, my NPM dependancies are not fetched and extracted into the lib folder as stated.

The only way I found to get the dependancies is to execute " web-assets:jseNpmNodeModules" command in activator, but the dependencies are extracted in node_modules directory, and not available as webjars.

Is there some secret configuration to do? A plugin to add?

This is exactly the same issue encountered here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/npm|sort:relevance/play-framework/Q2QCAsJCRg0/ees7qZuT8_0J

Thanks !

Comment: I think this is a related issue: [#3565](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3565).

Comment: It is, but the issue should not be closed, I'm not the only one having problems with npm integration